# Elements next to each other in div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="card-body" data-bind="if :showParam() || editParameters() ">
                <form class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: submitReportData">
                    <div id="input-holder" data-bind="foreach:mainData">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="form-group row">
                                <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: DisplayText, attr : {'for' : Name}"></label>
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Input' -->
                                <input style="width:100%" type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Checkbox' -->
                                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Value" class="checkbox input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && !MultiValue() -->
                                <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', value: Value, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && MultiValue() -->
                                <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', selectedOptions: Value, validationElement: Value" multiple style="height:150px !important;" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'AutoComplete' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: Value, attr : {'id':'autocomplete_' + Name()}" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.AutocompleteMessage" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DatePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DateTimePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'TimePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="timePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" style="margin:20px !important;" class="btn pull-right" id="generateReport"><em class="fa fa-repeat"></em> @SharedResources.Index.ShowReport</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

I have a div that contains input elements like text fields, datepickers, dropdown lists, etc. It's all located inside one div that has 'row' class. However, all the elements are shown below each other and I want them to be next to each other. How could I achieve this? Do I need  to wrap each element inside a separate div and give it 'row' class?

```
<div class="card-body" data-bind="if :showParam() || editParameters() ">
                <form class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: submitReportData">
                    <div id="input-holder" data-bind="foreach:mainData">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="form-group row">
                                <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: DisplayText, attr : {'for' : Name}"></label>
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Input' -->
                                <input style="width:100%" type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Checkbox' -->
                                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Value" class="checkbox input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && !MultiValue() -->
                                <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', value: Value, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && MultiValue() -->
                                <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', selectedOptions: Value, validationElement: Value" multiple style="height:150px !important;" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'AutoComplete' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: Value, attr : {'id':'autocomplete_' + Name()}" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.AutocompleteMessage" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DatePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DateTimePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'TimePicker' -->
                                <input type="text" data-bind="timePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" style="margin:20px !important;" class="btn pull-right" id="generateReport"><em class="fa fa-repeat"></em> @SharedResources.Index.ShowReport</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Pic of problem:

[image]

Comment: try giving a snippet please

Comment: The snippet unfortunately lists all elements at once when I run it so its kinda useless. But I added it anyway.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of how it looks like

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY I've added a screenshot to my post.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap each element inside a div and give that div class "col". See below:

```
      <div class="card-body" data-bind="if :showParam() || editParameters() ">
    <form class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: submitReportData">
      <div id="input-holder" data-bind="foreach:mainData">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col control-label" data-bind="text: DisplayText, attr : {'for' : Name}"></label>
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Input' -->
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="col form-control input-sm">
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Checkbox' -->
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Value" class="col checkbox input-sm">
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && !MultiValue() -->
            <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', value: Value, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm col"></select>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && MultiValue() -->
            <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', selectedOptions: Value, validationElement: Value" multiple style="height:150px !important;" class="col form-control input-sm"></select>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'AutoComplete' -->
            <input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: Value, attr : {'id':'autocomplete_' + Name()}" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.AutocompleteMessage" class="form-control input-sm col">
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DatePicker' -->
            <input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm col">
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DateTimePicker' -->
            <input type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm col">
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'TimePicker' -->
            <input type="text" data-bind="timePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm col">
            <!-- /ko -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" style="margin:20px !important;" class="btn pull-right" id="generateReport"><em class="fa fa-repeat"></em> @SharedResources.Index.ShowReport</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Or modify the html as per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms . Bootstrap has form-inline component too.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally make .`form-group.row`a flexbox.

```css
.form-group.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body" data-bind="if :showParam() || editParameters() ">
  <form class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: submitReportData">
    <div id="input-holder" data-bind="foreach:mainData">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="form-group row">
          <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: DisplayText, attr : {'for' : Name}"></label>
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Input' -->
          <input style="width:100%" type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Checkbox' -->
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Value" class="checkbox input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && !MultiValue() -->
          <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', value: Value, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' && MultiValue() -->
          <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', selectedOptions: Value, validationElement: Value" multiple style="height:150px !important;" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'AutoComplete' -->
          <input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: Value, attr : {'id':'autocomplete_' + Name()}" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.AutocompleteMessage" class="form-control input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DatePicker' -->
          <input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DateTimePicker' -->
          <input type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'TimePicker' -->
          <input type="text" data-bind="timePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
          <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" style="margin:20px !important;" class="btn pull-right" id="generateReport"><em class="fa fa-repeat"></em> @SharedResources.Index.ShowReport</button>
  </form>
</div>
```